# How to lazy load scripts in YUI that accompany ajax html fragments

Tags: ajax, yui

I have a web app with Tabs for Messages and Contacts (think gmail).  Each Tab has a Y.on('click') event listener that retrieves an HTML fragment via Y.io() and renders the fragment via node.setContent().

However, the Contact Tab also requires contact.js to enable an Edit button in the fragment.
How do I defer the cost of loading contact.js until the user clicks on the Contacts tab?
How should contact.js add it's listener to the Edit button?

The Complete function of my Tab's on('click') event could serialize Get.script('contact.js') after Y.io('fragment'). However, for better performance, I would prefer to download the script in parallel to downloading the HTML fragment. In that case, I would need to defer adding an event listener to the Edit button until the Edit button is available.

This seems like a common RIA design pattern.  What is the best way to implement this with YUI? How should I *get* the script? How should I defer sections of the script until elements in the fragment are *available* in the DOM?

Comment: Dav Glass, a YUI Engineer, replied on the YUI Forum
http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=3598&p=12393#p12393

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caridy's [Dispatcher module](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/dispatcher) can also handle this, and is probably my favorite solution to this issue atm. It was just covered in today's YUI Open Hours & it looks great.

Comment: it does look promising. i'm curious how it handles the script nodes.  i hope it doesn't call eval

Comment: @Chris Beck - it doesn't, you can view the source here: http://github.com/caridy/yui3-gallery/blob/master/src/gallery-dispatcher/js/gallery-dispatcher.js

It creates a DocumentFragment & injects the markup, then pulls out any script tags. When the markup is inserted it then either fetches any remote script tags or shoves any inline script tags into the head.

Comment: brilliant. that does exactly what i was wanted to do.  it even purges any existing listeners in the fragment it replaces.  we know it's good to separate JS from HTML, but having a single inline JS node in an HTML fragment IS separation without the cost of a extra HTTP request. you saved me a day or more trying to write this myself

Answer (score 0):

According to Dav:

"What I would do is in the IO callback for the HTML fragment, just after calling setContent, use Y.Get to load the script file:"

That is quite reasonable.